# HTC One hardware back button quirky in cordova 2.0.1 and newer

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have found a weird behavior that is in all versions of cordova after 2.0.0  ( as in cordova-2.0.0.jar )

This is in a html/css/jQuery/jQueryMobile mobile app on a HTC One X phone.  The problem is that the hardware back button goes back to the last data-role=page that the user viewed instead of just closing the soft-keyboard.  (LogCat log is below)

My question is: What can I do, using the latest version of the cordova API, so that the hardware back button just closes the keyboard, and does not go back to my most recent data-role=page?

The use case is:

- HTC One X phone
- open the app; it opens on page_1
- tap a footer button to go to page_3
- click a footer button to go back to page_1
- tap in an input box  (the soft keyboard comes up)
- tap the hardware back button

The soft keyboard closes and the app goes to page_3

- on cordova versions 1.9.0 and 2.0.0 the soft keyboard closes and the app stays on page_1
- all versions after 2.0.0 do it.
- I can't use the older version because they have issues with the Samsung Galaxy 3

The following html performs exactly as I have described.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GFE Tool</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/themeswf2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/css_gfe.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js" type="text/javascript">    
</script>
<script src="scripts/using_timios_ws.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="scripts/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

<section id="page_1" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

    <header data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
        <div class="standard_table our_header" >
            <span><img src="images/LogoWhite.png" width="187" height="61" alt="Timios logo"/></span>
            <span class="setup_gear" style="height: 61px;background-color:#4d4d4d;">
                <a id='the_gear' href="#setup_page">
                    <img src="images/geargray.png" width='61' height="61" alt="Set Up"/></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </header>

<div data-role="content" class="content">
<div >
    <table class='standard_table'>
        <tr><td><div class='page_title' >Enter Property Data</div>
                <div class='page_title' id='div_welcome_user'></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="number" />
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position='fixed'  align="center">
    <a id='get_results_2' href="#" >
        <div class="one_line_footer_button" >Get Closing Costs</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#page_3" id='CmdGoToNews'  >
        <div class="one_line_footer_button" >New at Our Company</div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>

</section>

<section id="page_3" data-role="page" data-theme="f">
<header data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
    <div class="standard_table our_header" >
        <a href="#page_1" >
        <span><img src="images/LogoWhite.png" width="187" height="61" alt="HEADER IMAGE"/></span>
        </a>
            <span class="setup_gear" style="height: 61px;background-color:#4d4d4d;">
        <a id="the_gear_3" href="#setup_page"><img src="images/geargray.png" width="61" height="61" alt="Set Up"/></a>
            </span>
    </div>
</header>

<div data-role="content" class="content">

    <div id='divNews' class="about_us" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; ">
    This is where New at our company goes.
    </div>

</div>

<div  data-role="footer" data-position='fixed' align="center" class='our_footer'>
    <a id="NewAccountSetup" href="#setup_page" >
        <div class="two_line_footer_button">New Account<br>Sign Up</div>
    </a>
    <a id='ClientSetup' href="#setup_page" >
        <div class="two_line_footer_button">Client<br>Sign In</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#page_1" >
        <div class='two_line_footer_button'>
            <img src='images/home_icon_white_36.jpg' />
        </div>
    </a>

</div>

</section>

</body>
```

NOTE: I am not using PhoneGap Build. I am creating the exec in eclipse.

The LogCat log (below) starts w the moment I hit the hardware back-button. It shows that CordovaWebView is tracking my "browser history" - The URL at index: 0 is ...  The log when I use the older versions of the cordova jar does not show these lines.

```
04-13 16:15:54.964: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(32763): Ignore this event
04-13 16:15:55.124: D/CordovaWebView(32763): The URL at index: 0is file:///android_asset/www/gfe_one.html
04-13 16:15:55.124: D/CordovaWebView(32763): The URL at index: 1is file:///android_asset/www/gfe_one.html#page_3
04-13 16:15:55.124: D/CordovaWebView(32763): The URL at index: 2is file:///android_asset/www/gfe_one.html#/android_asset/www/gfe_one.html
04-13 16:15:55.124: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(32763): Ignore this event
04-13 16:15:55.164: D/Cordova(32763): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/gfe_one.html#page_3)
04-13 16:15:55.164: D/Cordova(32763): Trying to fire onNativeReady
04-13 16:15:55.164: D/DroidGap(32763): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
04-13 16:15:55.164: D/DroidGap(32763): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/gfe_one.html#page_3)
04-13 16:15:56.475: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32763): <ConfigWindowMatch:1991>: Format RGBA_8888.
```

Comment: you need to add an event handler for back button once phonegap/cordova is loaded. Please refer this stackoverflow.com/questions/14207690/stop-exit-on-back-button-android-in-phonegap-build

Comment: @Nanashi paste your tip into an answer so I can give it the green checkmark and close this thing.  The sample app that comes with the cordova download I got from phone gap (cordova-2.6,0.jar etc) does the same thing as my app on the HTC One x.

Comment: Haven't heard from @Nanashi so I will paste his answer in as mine so I can close this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nanashi wrote:  *you need to add an event handler for back button once phonegap/cordova is loaded. Please refer this stackoverflow.com/questions/14207690/stop-exit-on-back-button-android-in-phonega‌​p-build*

NOTE: in my js function that now handles the hardware back button, I just did return;
The examples do other things or have // do stuff here

Answer (score 0):

Open your res/xml/config.xml file and look for:

```
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
```

You may want to play with the value of useBrowserHistory to return to the old way the back button worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response Simon. I found that the example project (ver 2.5.0) I got in the cordova download at the phonegap website (http://phonegap.com/download/)  I guess I will try to handle the back button event in code, unless you think its a bug and I should try to report it.  Thanks again.

Comment: What the example project does is this: tap in input box; soft keyboard opens; tap hardware back button; keyboard closes and the app closes.

Comment: Seems like it may be a bug. With my phone right now the when I'm in a text box the back button turns into a close keyboard button so I can't reproduce this. Open a bug on JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB